# Dynamic form inputs on Vuejs

Tags: javascript, vue.js

In my form I need to make a method for dynamically adding form fields to "add new user" and push them to my data array `founders: []`. My inputs that needs to be added to form just hidden inside of `<div id="new-user">` with `display:none`. Not sure that it's the right way, but I'm trying to do something like code below. 
So I need to figure out how correctly display my form fields at exact place as many times as user press on "Add new user" button and push at the same time data.

```
addFounderGrant() {
        var elem = document.createElement('#new-user'); //This part I need help
        this.step3.foundersGrants.push( {
            email:'',
            first_name:'',
            last_name:'',
            issue_date:'',
            certificate:'',
            share_price:'',
            shares_amount: '',
        } )
    },
```

I also tried this way, here my display form fields works fine, but data storing was wrong, too complex for me.

```
addFounder() {
        var counter = 0;
            counter++;
            var newFields = document.getElementById('new-user').cloneNode(true);

            newFields.id = '';
            newFields.style.display = 'block';
            var newField = newFields.childNodes;
            for (var i=0;i<newField.length;i++) {
                var theName = newField[i].name
                if (theName)
                    newField[i].name = theName + counter;
            var insertHere = document.getElementById('writeroot');
            insertHere.parentNode.insertBefore(newFields,insertHere);
        }
        this.step3.foundersGrants.push( {
            email:'',
            first_name:'',
            last_name:'',
            issue_date:'',
            certificate:'',
            share_price:'',
            shares_amount: '',
        } )
    },
```

Struggling 3rd day with this thing, please tip me what's the easiest way to do it right?

Comment: Create an array of objects including user details and render it through v-for on add of new user push an object into the array and would be automatically displayed in the template.

Comment: @Riddhi thanks dude, that works for me.

Comment: Accept the answer so that the question is closed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create an array of objects including user details and render it through v-for on add of new user push an object into the array and would be automatically displayed in the template.